# How to populate an array in order(Row by Row) in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I am trying to have my code populate the array row by row

the occupancy = 14

is it possible than the array i want outputted can be like this

```
1,1,1,1,1 

1,1,1,1,1 

1,1,1,1,0 

0,0,0,0,0 

0,0,0,0,0
```

thus the sum of the occupancy = 14

my code so far:

```
list_A_5x5 = [[0 for row in range (5)] for col in range (5)]

occupancy = 14 



while occupancy !=0:
 for i in range(5):
   list_A_5x5[0][i] = 1
   list_A_5x5[1][i] = 1
   list_A_5x5[2][i] = 1
   list_A_5x5[3][i] = 1
   list_A_5x5[4][i] = 1



 occupancy= occupancy-1
```

Comment: Hi, can you show us what have you tried, and which part of the problem are you having trouble with?

Comment: ive added an edit, sorry im new to stackoverflow

Comment: Your code will always fill up the list with 1. One way to help you visualise this is to put `print(list_A_5x5)` within the for loop. Hopefully it'll you understand why it's wrong